# Does the App Check metrics in firebase console show requests made by admin SDKs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, firebase-app-check

We are in the process of enabling App Check for our app, but the verified request percentages we are getting are much lower than expected. My gut feeling is that this is due to requests being made to our firebase services by our cloud functions via the node admin SDK.

Looking for confirmation on if we would expect these requests to show in our console as "Unverified" requests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Admin SDK requests should not show up as unverified requests and shouldn't show up in the App Check request metrics at all. Just like security rules, App Check does not apply to requests originating from the Admin SDK. If you find upon more research that the metrics are being reported incorrectly in the console, let Firebase Support know so we can investigate further.

Comment: Okay brilliant, thanks for confirming! I'll take a look through everything and try and work out the discrepancy from what we're expecting.

Comment: @simonthumper - if you go to the cloud console for monitoring you can split the traffic out by appids which are getting rejected.